# Can I customize the web.config transform for appharbor deployment?

Tags: git, deployment, appharbor, web-config-transform

Checking out AppHarbor today. My primary question is in the title, but I have other questions related to git + windows.

First of all, related to [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=J53_z4MdsHc#!). I like the idea that I can specify config transforms for deployment. My question is, does it have to be the Web.Release.config transform? I actually want to test this out by using it as a qa deployment for integration tests. Would I be able to specify the transform as Web.DeployToAppHarbor.config be used instead?

Secondly, I have read about the crlf problem. When I run `git add .`, am i supposed to get all of these messages?

```
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in [path].
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

Along those lines, am I also supposed to get all of these message after running `git commit -m "Initial commit"`?

```
create mode 100644 [path]
```

If these are normal, is there a way to make git bash less verbose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not going to be using one platform, it's advisable to have autocrlf to be set to false and not have Git change line endings on you.

AppHarbor will always apply the `Web.Release.config`. If you want alternate configurations for qa and others like "staging", you can have those but it's good to manage these in separate branches. When you merge to these branches, use --no-commit on the merge command and make sure the merge does not change them with `git checkout HEAD -- config`. Then finish the merge with `git commit`.

Better yet, you could keep the change of the config in a special branch where you change the properties of the config to those of production. After each merge, you could apply that commit as a patch. This would make it easy for other changes to the config to be merged in but after cherry-picking that one commit, you could change only those special properties to what you like.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am also new to git, but have been considering moving source from TFS to GitHub. Will have to revisit your recommendations later, for now, we don't use Release.config at all, so I can dedicate it to AppHarbor without worrying about anything being overwritten.

Comment: Excellent choice on moving away from TFS.

Comment: VS tooling is biggest holdback. Command prompts are my kryptonite, plus we have multiple developers who would have to switch. Phil Haack said GitHub has a job opening regarding the VS tooling thing, so I'm staying tuned.

Comment: Oh you will love the command line. It is absolutely awesome. Give it a try.

Comment: "you can have those but it's good to manage these in separate branches"

It's not good to manage them in seperate branches, it's just the only option right now.